# Another number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Any ideas of what comes next?

> 0, 0, 1, 5, 119....

*Note: this sequence cannot be found in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) and the solution is not obtained by fitting a polynomial function to these numbers*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are

> the factorials of the Fibonacci numbers minus 1.

Or

> $$a_n = F_n! - 1$$

For example

> $$1! - 1 = 0$$ $$1! - 1 = 0$$ $$2! - 1 = 1$$ $$3! - 1 = 5$$ $$5! - 1 = 119$$ $$\cdots$$

Thus, the next number is

> $$8! - 1 = \boxed{40319}$$

Comment: Good job, well done :-)

Answer (score -1):

I believe one should always include the fact that *THE REAL ANSWER IS SIMPLE*

as the solution

> $f(x) = \dfrac{35}{8}x^4 - \dfrac{311}{12}x^3+\dfrac{381}{8}x^2-\dfrac{313}{12} x$

also works...

Comment: Aaahh yes, I take  your point. about that. -- I was going to start adding hints like that if no one got it after a few hours

Comment: I will add an edit